What's MyNotificationActivator in DynamicComActivator Assembly?
I'm working on a MAUI app. Our app uses reflection to load modules dynamically from available DLLs. However, when loading our modules, some of our developers get this exception:

System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Could not load type 'MyNotificationActivator' from assembly 'DynamicComActivator, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.'
at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
at MyApp.Platform.TypeExtensions.GetClassesThatImplementInterfaceType(Assembly assembly, Type compareType)
at MyApp.Platform.TypeExtensions.GetClassesThatImplementInterfaceType[T](Assembly assembly)
at MyApp.Maui.AppModuleService.<>c.b__7_0(Assembly assembly)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.ToList()
at MyApp.Maui.AppModuleService.FinishAppInitialization()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.b__128_0(Object state)
at Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueueSynchronizationContext.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0()
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'MyNotificationActivator' from assembly 'DynamicComActivator, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

The code that throws this exception is here:
// in AppModuleService.FinishAppInitialization
var asyncTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(assembly => assembly.GetClassesThatImplementInterfaceType<IAsyncModule>())
    .ToList();

Specifically in one of the GetClassesThatImplementInterfaceType call. That method looks like this:
public static List<Type> GetClassesThatImplementInterfaceType<T>(this Assembly assembly)
{
    return assembly.GetClassesThatImplementInterfaceType(typeof(T));
}

public static List<Type> GetClassesThatImplementInterfaceType(this Assembly assembly, Type compareType)
{
    var ret = new List<Type>();
    foreach (var type in assembly.DefinedTypes)
    {
        if (compareType.IsAssignableFrom(type) && compareType != type && type.IsClass)
        {
            ret.Add(type);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

From what I understand about the ReflectionTypeLoadException, calling assembly.DefinedTypes internally calls assembly.GetTypes(), which may throw this exception if any of the types can't be loaded.
The type that couldn't be loaded seems to be MyNotificationActivator as outlined by the single LoaderException I find on the thrown ReflectionTypeLoadException.
Unfortunately, I don't know what this MyNotificationActivator type or DynamicComActivator assembly is. Additionally, it seems to work for some developers. So it seems that the assembly is somewhere to be found. I wasn't able to find any more information about this type or assembly.
I'm tempted to just use the workaround some people use with GetTypes() to just catch the exception and work with the types that were loaded, but I'd rather understand what's going on and fix it instead. Does anyone know what this type/assembly is and why I can't load it or find it in the NuGet gallery?
